# Do hotels omit the 13th floor?

Tags: psychology, elevators

[image: no 13th floor]<sub>([Image source](http://www.moneyandshit.com/13th-floor/))</sub>

[Triskaidekaphobia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triskaidekaphobia) is the **fear of the number 13**.

But do (western) hotels cater to this phobia by skipping/omitting the 13th floor?

This [USA Today article](http://www.usatoday.com/money/biztravel/2007-03-08-13th-floor-usat_N.htm) (2007) quotes **J.W. Marriott Jr.**, chairman of [Marriott International](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Marriott_International):

> "*It was one of the first things I
> learned: **Don't go to 13***. "

also from the article:

> Hotels without a designated 13th floor
> are so much the norm that fire
> departments generally assume it to be
> the case.
>
> "*Changing now would be the
> issue, and cause confusion*," says
> Alejandra Castro-Nuñez, spokeswoman
> for Miami-Dade's fire rescue and
> homeland security department.

**Dilip Rangnekar**, spokesman of the [Otis Elevator Company](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Otis_Elevator_Company) (2002):

> "***Based on records of buildings with
> Otis brand elevators, as many as 85%
> of the high rises in the world
> don't have a 13th floor***." ([source](http://realtytimes.com/rtpages/20020913_13thfloor.htm))

---

My question: 
**Are there statistics on how many hotels omit the 13th floor?**

Is it just a minority or actually a widespread phenomenon?

On a side note:

Apparently [there are airlines](http://blog.seattlepi.com/airlinereporter/2009/11/13/row-13-why-some-airlines-have-it-and-others-do-not/) (e.g. Air France, Lufthansa, Continental) that don't have a 13th row.

[image: no row 13]
<sub>([Image Source](http://www.wikinfo.org/index.php/Unlucky_13))</sub>

Comment: Wouldn't surprise me. A lot of buildings in China don't have a 4th floor cause 4 rhymes with death in Chinese

Comment: From personal experience, I have been to few that do not omit it. However in their defense, sometimes they omit other numbers too.

Comment: The last hotel I stayed in did not have rooms numbered 13. Straight from 612 to 614.

Comment: This might be different between USA and Europe. For example. I can find several German websites asking if this is true for the USA. It would surprise me for Germany, but it still might be the case, e.g. due to American influence. Also, many hotels in Europe might not even be higher than 12 floors anyway.

Comment: @stickman - Actually the 4 doesn't just rhyme with death it is pronounced exactly the same!

Comment: When I stayed at a hotel in Beijing in 2007, the floors 4, 13, 14, 24, 34, 44, 54, ... were missing.

Comment: It's not just hotels.  I have been in a major hospital in St. Louis that skips the number 13 in at least one of its towers.

Comment: @stickman: The condos built by Concord in Toronto and Vancouver (and there are many) don't have the number "4" for floors or rooms because of the Chinese stigma.

Comment: The "4" stigma also exists in Korea - one building I visited went from floor 3 to 5.

Comment: If I recall correctly, the rooms in Jindabyne accommodation organized by Oz Snow Adventures skips room number 13.

Comment: In hospitals (at least where I went) of South Korea, EVERY rooms doesn't have number 4. Like `502, 503, 505, ...` or `538, 539, 550, 551, ...`

Comment: It depends on a region I guess. I haven't seen "missing" 13 in Europe.

Answer (score 14):

Not about hotels, but an analysis about **all closed co-op and condo sales in Manhattan, in 2009**.

[Jonathan Miller](http://matrix.millersamuel.com/?p=9939)

> did an [analysis by floor level of
> Manhattan co-ops and condos](http://matrix.millersamuel.com/?p=8450), which
> illustrated the market phenomenon of
> the missing 13th floor in Manhattan.
>
> Older buildings are more likely to be missing the 13th floor than new ones.
>
> ...
>
> 13th floor – data suggests **only 18.4%
> of buildings with a 13th floor
> actually call it that.**

[image: building market share]

[Real Deal Magazine](http://therealdeal.com/newyork/articles/the-cost-of-a-view):

> Miller's analysis [...] found
> quantitative evidence that, yes,
> apartments on the 13th floor are
> statistically unusual (note that
> floor's small market share for 2009
> sales). That superstition, it seems,
> dies hard.

Comment: It would be interesting (but off-topic on Skeptics) to see if/how this depends on when the highrise was built.

Comment: I've observed quite a number of building exteriors where the amount of space above the twelfth row of windows and the next one up is somewhat greater than for other floors, suggesting that perhaps the "thirteenth floor" might be a utility crawlspace.